# PIL selection of coordinates to make an image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am wanting to create an image from a selection of coordinates i have. So I want each coordinate to be set a particular size and colour say black and 2X2, and then place it at the particular pixel it represents.
How will i go about this?
Will the function `putpixel`, work for what I want to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing this with `putpixel` will be inconvenient but not impossible. Since you say you want to make dots of more than a single pixel, it would be better to use [`ImageDraw.rectangle()`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagedraw.htm) or `ellipse()` instead.

For example:

```
import Image
import ImageDraw

img = Image.new("RGB", (400,400), "white")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

coords = [(100,70), (220, 310), (200,200)]
dotSize = 2

for (x,y) in coords:
    draw.rectangle([x,y,x+dotSize-1,y+dotSize-1], fill="black")

img.show()
```

Comment: hmm, sounds like a python challenge?!